# Manga where the main character gains a super weapon named after a demon

Tags: story-identification, manga

The setting was fantasy. There were these super weapons, all named after demons that took the form of giant machines. The main character's was a plane with an energy cannon that I think was named Lucifer. I remember another that was a giant train, and that each one had a weapon like a sword or lance that allowed the person to control them. I also remember there being a game, as well as maybe a light novel.

Comment: The names of demons from which culture?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: @Spencer All Ars Goetia demon names to my memory. Might have even just been the names of the Seven Deadly Sins demons.

Comment: @LogicDictates Mostly black and white classic manga style. Maybe a full color page or two at the very beginning, but not in a long webcomic format.